# Rails Paperclip result array index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I try to do method that get avatar from assets. My User.rb code:

```
def get_avatar(size)

if self.assets.length != 0
  self.assets.each do |asset|
    if asset.avatar
     asset.photo.url(size)
    end
  end
else
  default_avatar(size)
end
```

end

in view:

```
user.get_avatar(:small)
```

It should work but in view i have only this:

```
 <img alt="Jpeg&quot;, photo file size: 121649, photo updated at: &quot;2013 08 20 07:51:42&quot;, user id: 109, active: false, avatar: true&gt;]" src="/images/[#&lt;Asset id: 176, created_at: &quot;2013-08-20 07:51:43&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2013-08-20 07:51:43&quot;, photo_file_name: &quot;user_2.jpg&quot;, photo_content_type: &quot;image/jpeg&quot;, photo_file_size: 121649, photo_updated_at: &quot;2013-08-20 07:51:42&quot;, user_id: 109, active: false, avatar: true&gt;]">
```

It doesn't take photo.url(size) but whole array index.

When i do:

```
Rails.logger.fatal "check_me #{asset.photo.url(size)}"
```

It return only photo url. But still it doesn't work.

When i do :

```
self.assets.first.photo.url(size)
```

it works. What is the difference?

Comment: What are you doing? What does self refer to and what are assets? Post the model that has the attachments here. Only then we can make out what you are trying to do?

Comment: its very simple - if its User.rb soo self refer to User model.

Comment: Ok. So the model is User.rb. Please post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `get_avatar` function, you loop the assets array, when you get an asset's url, you don't return it, so the function returns array itself. so add return when you get the url.

```
def get_avatar(size)

  if self.assets.length != 0
    self.assets.each do |asset|
      if asset.avatar
        return asset.photo.url(size)
      end
    end
  else
    default_avatar(size)
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.